# My table displays and then disappears after I click submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, submit

I am trying to build a 2-dimensional table where width = x, and height = y. I'm almost there, but when I click the submit button, the desired x,y table displays and then disappears after I click submit. I tried running makeGrid(5, 5); at the end of the JS file, i.e. manually adding in values for makeGrid(h, w), and the table displays and does not go away. But I need to be able to have the table construct from the submit button without disappearing.

Please help. Thank you!!

I believe the main issue is just with the JavaScript portion but I included all three (html, css, js) just to be comprehensive.

[Image of three different states of the webpage, from left to right (before click, immediately after clicking submit, and moments after clicking submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4eDH.png)

```js
var color, h, w;

const myTable = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');

function colorCell(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor =
    document.querySelector('#colorPicker').value;
}

function makeGrid(h, w) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
    const newTR = document.createElement('tr'); // Creates height amount of rows
    for (let i = 1; i <= w; i++) {
      const newTD = document.createElement('td'); // Creates width amount of columns
      newTR.appendChild(newTD);
    }
    myTable.appendChild(newTR); // Adds the row to the table before iterating again
  }
}

myTable.addEventListener('click', colorCell);

let form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function submitFunction() {
  h = document.querySelector('#inputHeight').value;
  w = document.querySelector('#inputWidth').value;
  makeGrid(h, w);
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Monoton;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
}

input[type='number'] {
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>
    <h2>Choose Your Grid Size</h2>
    <h4>(to reset, click Submit again)</h4>
    <form id="sizePicker">
      Grid Height:
      <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1" />
      Grid Width:
      <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <h2>Choose Any Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker" />

    <h2>Create your art in the table below!</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because any submit do a page reload. use preventDefault() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent the browser's default submit event by using `e.preventDefault()` and `e` is passed to the `submitFunction()`.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function submitFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  h = document.querySelector('#inputHeight').value;
  w = document.querySelector('#inputWidth').value;
  makeGrid(h, w);
});
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault*

---

#### Result (in Code Snippet):

```js
var color, h, w;

const myTable = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');

function colorCell(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor =
    document.querySelector('#colorPicker').value;
}

function makeGrid(h, w) {
  myTable.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
    const newTR = document.createElement('tr'); // Creates height amount of rows
    for (let i = 1; i <= w; i++) {
      const newTD = document.createElement('td'); // Creates width amount of columns
      newTR.appendChild(newTD);
    }
    myTable.appendChild(newTR); // Adds the row to the table before iterating again
  }
}

myTable.addEventListener('click', colorCell);

let form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function submitFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  h = document.querySelector('#inputHeight').value;
  w = document.querySelector('#inputWidth').value;
  makeGrid(h, w);
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Monoton;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
}

input[type='number'] {
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>
    <h2>Choose Your Grid Size</h2>
    <h4>(to reset, click Submit again)</h4>
    <form id="sizePicker">
      Grid Height:
      <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1" />
      Grid Width:
      <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <h2>Choose Any Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker" />

    <h2>Create your art in the table below!</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That fixed the issue with the table not appearing but it created a new problem.

Now when I try to 'refresh' and start over, the Submit button just adds on to the existing table (instead of building a new table). What I mean by this is if I start with 15 x 15, it builds it. If I click Submit with width and height at 15 x 15, it creates a 15 x 30 table. The height increases forever but the width stays the same.

Comment: @newprogrammer627 Simply add `myTable.innerHTML = '';` in `makeGrid(h, w)` function in the first line. This will reset the table every time the submit button is clicked.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet if you want to see the final result. Happy coding!